# Block `//xmlrpc.php`

Tags: security, .htaccess, wordpress, apache2

I'm getting tens of thousands of (quite probably malicious) hits on Apache which are bringing the server down. All hits look like this on the Apache log:

```
[30/Jan/2022:21:57:41 +0000] "POST //xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 200 630 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4240.193 Safari/537.36"
```

(**Note the double slash**. I don't know what it means.)

I have added the rule below on .htaccess to try to mitigate the server load:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^//xmlrpc.php
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

When I run `curl -kIL -X POST -H 'Host: [REDACTED]' https://127.0.0.1:443/xmlrpc.php`, I get the 403 error code.

However, apparently it is not enough: according to the log, Apache keeps returning 200 for the requests with two slashes. How can I block these requests (return 403)? How can I use curl / wget / etc to check if the block is active?

**I need a rule to prevent "POST //xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" from returning 200 (HTTP OK) and return 403 instead.**

Comment: *but the //xmlrpc.php keep showing on the log.* Its not clear for me. Is the issue related to double slash? `//`.  403 response mean *it works*, but the rule does not prevent requests to be logged, it's another thing.

Comment: I need a rule to prevent `"POST //xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1"` from returning 200 (HTTP OK). How do I achieve that?

Comment: I just tested the RewriteCond and it does not work. The only thing that works is `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/xmlrpc.php`, with 1 slash, wich block both `/xmlrpc.php` and `//xmlrpc.php`. If you want to block all requests its good for you, but if you want to block only requests with double slash, I dont't know.

Answer (score 1):

Disable XML-RPC on your WordPress installation as quickly as possible.
It is a big security risk, and the problem you are seeing now is only the beginning of it.
See for example https://www.getastra.com/blog/cms/wordpress-security/wordpress-xml-rpc-exploit-everything-you-need-to-know/ for details. (Not affiliated in any way.)